# How to maintain the size of fonts in anchored MSGraph Chart object

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a anchored `MSGraph Chart` object on my form to stretch left and bottom. It stretches well but the fonts also stretch. How do I maintain the same font size for all the `Data labels` but still be able to view the graph in full size on stretched or zoomed mode? My aim is to keep font sizes for all `Data labels` and `Axis` to `11pt`. The original font size for the Data Labels and Axis is `8pt`

**Edit:**

I have notice that when I select the `Zoom` or `Stretch` features in the Chart's properties sheet, the chart stretches and the so does the fonts. This does not happen if I select `Clip`

Is it possible to make the chart stretch whilst maintaining the font sizes to 11pt? I am asking this because when I looked at the chart on a 4:3 screen today, some fonts were barely visible. Please see the image of my current graph and together with its properties settings below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'anchored'? Exactly how do you accomplish this stretching? I use MSGraph and cannot replicate issue. Are you sure this is MSGraph and not Modern Chart? Attaching files for download is not appreciated in SO. All info to analyze an issue is supposed to be within question narrative.

Comment: @June7 first of all, thank you for your reply. On the form I have added `MSGraph8` object named `myGraph` Then I clicked on the object and selected `arrange` from the `main ribbon`, and selected `anchoring`, then `stretch down and across`. Apologies for sharing attachment as I thought it may help. I will edit to remove.

Comment: I followed those steps and do not get the effect you show. In fact, I see no difference from not making those settings. I have never used this and I have built quite a few graphs. What benefit do you expect? There are other forum sites where providing file download is encouraged.

Comment: Hi @June7 I have edited the OP. I would see the benefit of this on a 4:3 screen. Also, I have removed the download link. I am thinking that perhaps you are not seeing the fonts stretching because your charts `Size mode` could be in a `Clip` mode? Please see the second image of the post.

Comment: Nope, it is Stretch mode by default. Never changed. I was not aware needed to change screen ratio. I think the answer to your question is No. Since this is a design issue and there is no code for analysis, question really not appropriate to SO.

Comment: @June7 I have found a workable solution. Please have a look at my recent post to the solution I found for this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have inserted a `Stacked Layout` with two `cells` onto the the form, then inserted the `chart object` in the first `cell` and left the second cell empty.
A good thing is that an empty cell can be `anchored` to `Strech` when the form resizes to suit the screen's aspect ratio.
I then adjusted the `height` of the blank cell and `anchored` both the object and the blank cell to `Sctrech Down and Across`.
On the chart properties, the chart `Size Mode` must be set to `Strecth`

Then used the below code on the form open event:
Note: This code requires the use of `Microsoft Graph Object Library` which should be added using the `Tools -> References` feature on the code editor.
I am using `Microsoft Graph 16.0 Object Library`.
I shall be exploring how to use `latebinding` inorder to avoid this step or perhalps somone can comment.

```
Dim myChart As Graph.Chart
Dim myChartSeries As Graph.Series
Dim mySeriesDataLabel As Graph.DataLabel

Set myChart = Me.myGraph.Object

For Each myChartSeries In myChart.SeriesCollection

For Each mySeriesDataLabel In myChartSeries.DataLabels
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    mySeriesDataLabel.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
mySeriesDataLabel.Font.Size = 8
Next mySeriesDataLabel
Next myChartSeries

With Me.myGraph.Axes(1).TickLabels.Font
    .Name = "Times New Romans"
    .FontStyle = "Normal"
    .Size = 8
End With

With Me.myGraph.Axes(2).TickLabels.Font
    .Name = "Times New Romans"
    .FontStyle = "Normal"
    .Size = 8
End With
```

**Without Anchoring:**

[image]

**After Anchoring:**
[image]

[image]